# materialize + pug(jade) no funciona?

Tags: html5, css3, jade, materialize, pug

Tengo en mi layout esto

```
doctype html
html
  head
    title= title
    script(src="/javascripts/jquery-1.9.1.js")
    link(rel='stylesheet', type='text/css', href='/stylesheets/materialize.min.css')
    script(src="/javascripts/materialize.min.js")
  body
    block content
```

y en mi archivo .jade:

```
extends layoutPresentacion

block content   

    nav
      div(class="nav-wrapper   #000000 black") 
        a(href="" class="brand-logo") Key
```

no funciona, intente de varias maneras y nada

este es mi html que quiero pasarlo a .jade

```
<nav>
  <div class="nav-wrapper   #000000 black">
    <a href="" class="brand-logo" >KeyBIOMETRIC</a>
    <ul id="nav-mobile" class="right hide-on-med-and-down">
      <li><a href=""><i class="material-icons left">playlist_add</i>ingresar</a></li>
      <li><a href=""><i class="material-icons left">description</i>registrar</a></li>
     <li><a href=""><i class="material-icons left">supervisor_account</i>informacion</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: `div.clase1.clase2`

Comment: tienes alguna red social para poder comunicarme contigo?

Comment: ¿Por qué te complicas? 1. Leete la documentación. 2. Usa un compilador online como [HTML2Jade](http://html2jade.org/).

Answer (score 1):

Antes del código debes repasar temas como marcado html y css.

Para materialize class="black" en el div(class="nav-wrapper") te cambia el background-color del elemento a negro, no necesitas #000000 como clase, css no reconoce ese valor. Y como dice gustavo puedes usar HTML2Jade. o codepen.io para hacer ese trabajo de trabajar pug

```
- var title = 'title'

 doctype html
 html
     head
         title= title
         script(src="/javascripts/jquery-1.9.1.js")
         link(rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='/stylesheets/materialize.min.css')
         script(src="/javascripts/materialize.min.js")
     body
         nav
            div(class="nav-wrapper black") 
               a.brand-logo(href='') KeyBIOMETRIC
               ul#nav-mobile.right.hide-on-med-and-down
                 li
                   a(href='')
                     i.material-icons.left playlist_add
                     | ingresar
                 li
                   a(href='')
                     i.material-icons.left description
                     | registrar
                 li
                   a(href='')
                     i.material-icons.left supervisor_account
                     | informacion
```